# How can I change url parameters in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router

For example I have a url `/videos/5` which shows page `5` of my videos page. How can I use the Angular router to change to page `3` for example. Is there a way to 'relatively navigate' like without having to pass `videos` to the url.

Something like:

```
this.router.navigate([`/${pageNumber}`])
```

(page number is the number of the page I want to go to like /videos/3)

I looked around but can't find a solution I tried

```
this.router.navigate([`../${pageNumber}`], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute.parent })
```

But it's giving me errors.

How to achieve this with **Angular router** and **relative urls**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `relativeTo` with instance of `ActivatedRoute`, like this:

```js
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

...

constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
) { }

...

this.router.navigate([`../${pageNumber}`], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute })
```

Comment: That works! I was messing around with the point point slash and relative to but didn't try that combination yet. Thank you :)